# block function until it finishes returning.

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, vagrantfile

```
   cluster_size = 5 
   def build_namenode_box( config )
      vmname = "namenode"
      config.vm.define vmname.to_sym do |namenode|
          namenode.vm.box = "dummy"
          namenode.vm.provision :chef_solo, preserve_order: true do |chef|
             chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
             chef.roles_path = "roles"
             chef.add_role "test"
             chef.data_bags_path = "data_bags"
             chef.add_recipe "cloudera::namenode"
             chef.add_recipe "cloudera-cluster"
           end
           namenode.vm.provision :hostmanager
           namenode.vm.provision :shell, :inline => $script
      end
    end

    def build_slaves_boxes( config, cluster_size )
      (1..cluster_size).each do |i|
        vmname = "slave#{i}"
        config.vm.define vmname.to_sym do |slave|
          slave.vm.box = "dummy"
          slave.vm.provision :chef_solo, preserve_order: true do |chef|
            chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
            chef.roles_path = "roles"
            chef.add_role "test"
            chef.data_bags_path = "data_bags"
            chef.add_recipe "cloudera::datanode"
            chef.add_recipe "cloudera-cluster"
          end
          slave.vm.provision :shell, :inline => $slavescript
        end
      end  
    end

    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
      config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
      config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
        config.vm.box = "dummy"
        aws.access_key_id = "myid"
        aws.secret_access_key = "my_key"
        aws.keypair_name = "my_key"
        aws.ami = "ami-7747d01e"
        aws.security_groups = ["my_group"]
        override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
        override.ssh.private_key_path = "#{current_dir}/my_key.pem"
      end

      config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
          config.vm.box = "precise64"
          config.vm.box_url =  "https://vagrantcloud.com/chef/ubuntu-12.04/version/1/provider/virtualbox.box"
          v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"] 
      end

      #block the program until it returns. 
      build_namenode_box( config )
      # have to wait until the build_namenode_box() returns
      build_slaves_boxes( config, cluster_size )
    end
```

I'm building a Vagrantfile (in Ruby) to create a Cloudera Hadoop cluster. The problem it was creating is the following: 
Vagrant doesn't enforce the order (don't wait until the order defined vm's to finish execution).
So I need to wait until `namenode` is finished, because the datanodes in the slaves started before the jobtracker. The solution? block the `build_namenode_box()` function until it finished. I'm very raw in Ruby, so how can I write a function blocker that waits until the `build_namenode_box()` to return before executing the `build_slaves_boxes()` function? How can I use `yield` to accomplish that?

Comment: You could wrap your `vagrant up` calls in a Rakefile. This allows you to define dependencies. Also, a single `vagrant up machine` call will block until it's finished.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in plain Vagrant, as you noted it doesn't support inter-VM dependencies. You can look at using either an external script that just calls `vagrant up $name` in the correct order or something more complex like chef-metal to manage provisioning.